# How to get the value of Transform matrix T in system defined function affine2d show it in GUI

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Hi I am trying to get the value inside a preDefined function affine2D which is used by estimateGemoetricTransform.
I am able to open the affine2D with 
     edit affine2D; 
command in command window. I need the values of the transform matrix T and inverse T which is computed in it and display it in a GUI.

I tried using global but it says error writing affine2d.m

Comment: So if I understand your problem correctly, you probably don't have user privileges to modify internal MATLAB functions wherever they are located on your system. Try making your own variant (e.g. `my_affine2D.m`) and saving it somewhere where you *are* allowed to write. Then modify the other functions as appropriate to call your version.

Comment: It seem like a nice idea i'll try..

Comment: I had problem in getting the work space element to GUI.. but using global variable solved the problem.. It works fine.thanks :)